# Move Outlook mails to file on hard drive

Tags: microsoft-outlook

It’s becoming very difficult for me to store Outlook mails in limited size of 95MB. I generally use to delete many old mails and some important I have saved using the “Save As” option. But I am not able to save more than one mail at a time and also it is difficult to search for a particular mail. I searched for this problem and got one solution as I can create one file and that file will hold the mails.

Can anybody guide me to do this? Actually I am Gmail user from starting and never had such space limitation problem.

Comment: Outlook offers to "Archive" your emails from time to time you should take Outlook up on that offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if I drag and drop emails to the folder then I am able to save multiple emails at a time.

However my question was little different. I again searched for the partial solution as mentioned in above question and I found the solution that I can create special files for Outlook which are .pst files. These files remain on hard disk and can be imported to Outlook.

This option is under File-> Account setting-> Account setting-> Data files. Now this file can be accessed like a folder in Outlook and I can also apply filter to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Outlook you should be able to just select all the emails and drag them to a folder, where they'll be stored in .msg format.

Comment: If I select multiple mails and try to save them it shows .txt while saving. So unfortunately I had to one by one only.

Comment: Have you tried just dragging the emails to a folder?